# EMR - Airflow to run scala jar file airflow.exceptions.AirflowException

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, airflow, amazon-emr, mwaa

I am trying to run a scala jar file from AIRFLOW using emr and the jar file is designed to read mssql-jdbc and postgresql.

From airflow, I'm able to create cluster [image]

My SPARK_STEPS looks like

```
SPARK_STEPS = [
    {
        'Name': 'Trigger_Source_Target',
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
            'Args': ['spark-submit', 
                     '--master', 'yarn', 
                     '--jars', '/mnt/MyScalaImport.jar', 
                     '--class', 'org.classname', 
                     's3://path/SNAPSHOT.jar', 
                     'SQL_Pwd', 'PostgreSQL_PWD', 'loadtype'],
        }
    }
]
```

After this I have JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES defined-

```
JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    "Name": "pfdt-cluster-airflow",
    "LogUri": "s3://path/elasticmapreduce/",
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.4.0",
    "Applications": [
        {"Name": "Spark"},
    ],
    "Instances": {
        "InstanceGroups": [
            {
                "Name": "Master nodes",
                "Market": "ON_DEMAND",
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "InstanceCount": 1,
            }
        ],
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": True,
        "TerminationProtected": False,
        'Ec2KeyName': 'pem_file_name',
        "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet-123"
    },
    'BootstrapActions': [
        {
            'Name': 'import custom Jars',
            'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                'Path': 's3://path/subpath/copytoolsjar.sh',
                'Args': []
            }
        }
    ],
    'Configurations': [
      {
        'Classification': 'spark-defaults',
        'Properties': {
          'spark.jars': 's3://jar_path/mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar'
         }
      }
    ],
    "VisibleToAllUsers": True,
    "JobFlowRole": "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole",
    "ServiceRole": "EMR_DefaultRole",
    "Tags": [
        {"Key": "Environment", "Value": "Development"},
    ],
}
```

To copy the scala .jar file from S3 to local to airflow- I have a shell script which does the work: Path- s3://path/subpath/copytoolsjar.sh

> aws s3 cp s3://path/SNAPSHOT.jar /mnt/MyScalaImport.jar

On triggering the airflow-
It fails at node watch_step [image]

Errors what I'm getting are-
stdout.gz => [image]
stderr.gz =>

> 22/04/08 13:38:23 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 25.5907 ms
> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$2(JDBCOptions.scala:108)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:38)

How to resolve this issue-
I have my jars at-

> s3://path/subpath/mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar

> s3://path/subpath/postgresql-42.2.24.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload jar files(mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar, postgresql-42.2.24.jar) to airflow local-

In the bootstrap step-
`'BootstrapActions': [ { 'Name': 'import custom Jars', 'ScriptBootstrapAction': { 'Path': 's3://path/subpath/copytoolsjar.sh', 'Args': [] } } ]`

In copytoolsjar.sh file write the command as-
`aws s3 cp cp s3://path/SNAPSHOT.jar /mnt/MyScalaImport.jar && bash -c "sudo aws s3 cp s3://path/subpath/mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/" && bash -c "sudo aws s3 cp s3://path/subpath/postgresql-42.2.24.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/"`
Work will be done